# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - java

Tags: java, arrays

I want 31842 to be stored in an array:

```
arr[49] would store 2

arr[48] would store 4

arr[47] would be 8

arr[46] would be 1

arr[45] would be 3

arr[0]..arr[44] would all be 0
```

I wrote code to do it, but an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error bumps up! Any ideas?

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int [] integer1 = new int[50];
    int [] integer2 = new int[50];
    String string;
    char ch;

    System.out.print("Please enter an integer #1: ");
    string = scan.nextLine();
    for (int i = integer1.length; i > 0; i--){
      int position = string.length()-1;
      ch = string.charAt(position--);
      if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
        int chToInt = ch - '0';
        integer1[i] = chToInt;
        System.out.println(integer1[0]);
        }
      else{
        int chToInt = 0;
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
for (int i = integer1.length; i > 0; i--){
```

to:

```
for (int i = integer1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
```

`integer1.length` is `50`, and it's not a valid index in your array. Array indices start at `0` and end at `array.length - 1`.

That's not the only problem with your code, though:

`position` should be initialized outside the loop, and `ch = string.charAt(position--);` is valid only as long as `position >= 0`.

This should work:

```
int position = string.length()-1;
for (int i = integer1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  if (position >= 0)
    ch = string.charAt(position--);
  else
    ch = 0;
  if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') { 
    integer1[i] = ch - '0';
    System.out.println(integer1[i]);
  } else {
    integer1[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should change to `i >= 0` too.

Comment: @BackSlash That's correct, though it would make no difference in this specific case, since OP wants the start of the array to holds zeroes, which is the default value.

Comment: @Eran thank you! It worked perfectly.. It always seems silly after discovering the issue!! :)

Answer (score -1):

int i = integer1.length -1

Change to this in the for loop

and also intitialize the position variable outside of the for loop, else it will always give you the same character

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int [] integer1 = new int[50];
    int [] integer2 = new int[50];
    String string;
    char ch;

    System.out.print("Please enter an integer #1: ");
    string = scan.nextLine();
    int position = string.length()-1;
    for (int i = integer1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){

      ch = string.charAt(position--);
      int chToInt;
      if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
        chToInt = ch - '0';
        System.out.println(integer1[0]);
        }
      else{
        chToInt = 0;
      }
      integer1[i] = chToInt;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are *zero-based* in Java, if you have an array of size 50, the indexes will run from 0 to 49:

0 1 2 3 4 ... 49 - sums up to 50.

See the [**JLS - Chapter 10. Arrays**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) for details:

> ... we say n is the length of the array; **the components of the array are
>   referenced using integer indices from 0 to n - 1, inclusive**.

So when you do:

```
for (int i = integer1.length; i > 0; i--)
                     ↑
             length returns 50
```

You're actually out of bounds. Change `integer1.length` to `integer1.length - 1`.

Also note that you're not taking the very first element, which is at the 0 position, you'll also need to change `i > 0` to `i >= 0`.

Answer (score -1):

Array length and array last index are not same.
Last index of an array always array length-1 since index of an array starts with 0 rather than 1.

so, change your for loop

```
for (int i = (integer1.length - 1); i >= 0; i--){

//do operations
}
```